# How to mock a variable and method in Abstract Class?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

In a Java (Spring Boot) app, I use JUnit and Mockito and want to test the following service method:

```
public Page<EmployeeDTO> findAll(EmployeeRequest request, final Sort sort) {
    

    final List<EmployeeDTO> list = getDTOList(request);

    // code omitted for brevity
}
```

The `getDTOList` method is in the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class CustomCriteriaQueries {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    protected void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    protected List<D> getDTOList(EmployeeRequest request) {

        final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

        // code omitted

        return entityManager
                .createQuery(cq)
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

I tried to mock `EntityManager` using `@Mock` and stub via `mockito.when().then()`, but as far as I see, it cannot be mocked as in concrete classes. So, how should I mock the variables and methods in abstract class?

Comment: Please provide your test code so we could find the problem.

Comment: You have to mock a particular implementation and not the abstract class itself. Write a test that covers the abstract logics and extend the one when you test an implementation.

Comment: You can mock the abstract class itself just fine: `@Test public void test() { CustomCriteriaQueries mock = Mockito.mock(CustomCriteriaQueries.class); Mockito.when(mock.getDTOList()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
List<String> dtoList = mock.getDTOList();
assertEquals(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"), dtoList);
}`

Comment: @WildDev What do you mean?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer You realize that test only tests that Mockito's mocking works, right?

Comment: @DavidConrad yes. It is just a proof of concept as its unclear to me, what exactly should be tested here. Also, in my opinion `getDTOList(request)` should always return the same value for a unit test

Comment: To write a test you will need to mock the method calls. Just make an abstract test class that realizes the shared test logics and extend it every time you test an implementation. You never have to test the abstract class itself.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Thanks a lot, it seems logical. But I tried this and still the same problem. When I run test, the code hits the `getDTOList` method in the abstract class end gives "NullPointerException" error.  I checked the parameters passed to `getDTOList` method, there is no problem with them. So, any idea? I also cannot debug  `getDTOList` method as it is in abstract class.

Comment: @WildDev Could you post an example please? I have never used that approach. Any help please?

Comment: **Now** the code hits the method in the abstract class, but `entityManager` is null and as it has no getter, I cannot mock it in my Test method. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion use Mockito.when(CustomCriteriaQueries.class), then mock any method that you need to use.

```
@Test
public void testMethod(){
    CustomCriteriaQueries customCriteriaQueries = Mockito.when(CustomCriteriaQueries.class);
  
Assert.anyOperationYouNeed(customCriteriaQueries.getDTOList(this.buildEmployeeRequest));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems logical. But I tried this and still the same problem. When I run test, the code hits the `getDTOList` method in the abstract class end gives "NullPointerException" error.  I checked the parameters passed to `getDTOList` method, there is no problem with them. So, any idea? I also cannot debug  `getDTOList` method as it is in abstract class.

Comment: **Now** the code hits the method in the abstract class, but `entityManager` is null and as it has no getter, I cannot mock it in my Test method. Any idea?

Comment: create a private method buildEmployeeRequest of return type EmployeeRequest  in the test class and in the method create a object of the EmployeeRequest  and then set the values and then just the created object. By this you'll get the object you required.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is much more related to the method in the abstract class. Because even if I try the approach you suggested, my code will still hit the abstract class and throw exception. Am I wrong?